# return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'STRING' when building machine leaning model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

I'm getting the following error: `return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)`
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'BOX72'`(BOX72 is a value under column5).

The error seems to come at the line with code `impute_knn.fit_transform(X)`

Here is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',')

le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = dataframe

dfle2 = dfle.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')

newdf = dfle2[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']]

X = dataframe[['column1', 'column2', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']].values

y = dfle.column3

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

impute_knn = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
impute_knn.fit_transform(X)

ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

I know I can probably use something like `strip()`, but I can't seem to figure out how I use it to remove any space before or after a string for all cells (in case there are other similar value entries). I also, don't know if this is actually the solution. Any pointers or help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Most sklearn models/methods/functions can't take any strings as inputs. Convert the strings in your data to numeric before trying to put them through `fit` methods. Things like `lebelencoder` or the [sklearn "Working with text data" article](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) can be helpful